# CreateInstance Returns "The specified module could not be found."

Tags: c++, com, windows-server-2003, com+, createinstance

I've been trying to get a program that worked on `Windows 2000` to work on `Windows 2003`.  Everything I've had to do so far to get the program to work on `Windows 2003` has had to do with incorrect configuration.  Right now, this piece of code:

```
chr = pAdapterEnvPtr.CreateInstance(__uuidof(PFADAPTERMNGLib::PFAdapterEnv));
```

is returning:

```
0x8007007E
```

or in other words:

```
The specified module could not be found.
```

I have two other programs and another .dll and I can successfully create instances of those classes.  But this seems to fail.

I have used `Procmon` to try to figure out what the program can't find, but `Procmon` did not display anything that could indicate that the program could not find something.

In `OleView`, if I try to create an instance of the class, I see the following image:

[image: IClassFactory::CreateInstance failed. The specified module could not be found. severity: SEVERITY_ERROR, facility: FACILITY_WIN32 ($8007007E]

If you look on the left side of the image, trying to create an instance of `PFComgMng` gives me the same error.  (`PFAdapterEnv` and `PFCompMng` use the same process, `PFAdapterMng.exe`.)  However, `PFMQMonitor`, `PFSend`, and `PFTrace` all work correctly.  (Which use `PFMQListen.exe`, `PFSend.dll`, and `PFTraceService.exe`.)

Another thing that I wanted to note is that the following piece of code:

```
hr = pPFCompMng.CreateInstance(__uuidof(PFADAPTERMNGLib::PFCompMng));
```

works perfectly fine when it gets called earlier from `PFAdapterMng.exe`.  So it seems like `PFAdapterMng.exe` can successfully find the module and create the instance, but any other processes that try to create either of the instances of the classes within `PFAdapterMng.exe` can't find the module, resulting in this error.

Since `Procmon` isn't helping with this specific case, does anyone know what I could do to figure out what's keeping other processes from finding the module?

UPDATE:

I can't run `Dependency Walker` with profiling because `PFAdapterMng.exe` and `PFTraceService.exe` must be run as services.  I tried to run `Dependency Walker` while profiling `OleView` and tried to create instances of `PFAdapterEnv` and `PFCompMng` to try to find out why I was getting the `Module not found` message box.  Unfortunately, `Dependency Walker` didn't show that anything was missing.

UPDATE2:

Maybe I missed something in the `Procmon` log, so I created a new log by capturing events right before I stepped over the call to `CreateInstance` and right after the call.  Maybe someone else could take a look and tell me if i missed it?  I simply can't find any indications that `PFMQListen.exe` could not find something..

Here's a link to a zipped folder with a `Procmon` file, a `.csv` file, and a `.xml` file.

http://www.mediafire.com/?07jq8zj7emmpsvd

UPDATE3:

So, I managed to get `Dependency Walker` running under Profile mode to create an instance of `PFAdapterEnv`.  `Dependency Walker` did not find any missing `.dll`'s.

So, `Procmon` doesn't show anything, and neither does `Dependency Walker`.  I was stepping through the code at the assembly level with `ollydbg`, and I noticed that the error was created in the function `NdrClientCall2`.  I don't know if this means anything.

Any ideas as to what else I can try?  Do people need more information to help me solve this problem?  If so, please ask.

UPDATE4:

I tried using `/RegServer` to register the applications, and it worked.  I tried using `/RegServer` previously, where I just unregistered everything using `/UnregServer`.  This time, I also deleted the component from `Component Services` which I needed to have because I wanted to run `PFAdapterMng` under another identity.

So, it seems like everything works when running on `/RegServer` and double-clicking the applications.  However, I would like everything to run under a different configuration.

How do I configure everything to get the applications to work as follows:

`PFAdapterMng.exe` - Register as `/Service` and run under another identity through `services.msc`
`PFTraceServer.exe` - Register as `/Service` and run under another identity through `services.msc`

`PFMQListen.exe` - Register as `/RegServer` which will be started by `PFAdapterMng`
`PFMQSend.dll` - Registered with `Regsvr32` and loaded by `PFAdapterMng`

Thanks,
Krzys

Comment: ProcMon should most certainly help you find the missing DLL, you'll see the program searching for it.  Finding the needle in the haystack does require some effort.

Comment: `PFMQListen.exe` is the process that calls `CreateInstance` and gets the error, but `Procmon` does not show anything that would indicate that `PFMQListen.exe` is missing something.  I'll update my question with the `Procmon` log so maybe someone else might find something I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it is related to the search path of some DLL dependencies of the executable.
You can try the "Dependency Walker" on every module to see if all DLL are available: http://www.dependencywalker.com/
And update the search PATH if needed.

Comment: Yes, I tried this on `PFAdapterMng.exe`, `PFMQListen.exe`, `PFMQSend.dll`, and `PFTraceService.exe` and the only things missing were `wer.dll` and `ieshims.dll`, which I believe is normal.  Besides those two libraries, everything was found.  I'd like to profile my programs, but I can't because `PFAdapterMng.exe` and `PFTraceService.exe` must be run as services, while `PFMQListen.exe` is started by `PFAdapterMng.exe`.

Comment: Have you tried running the .exe with the argument "-Service"? It should be 'profilable' with this one.

Comment: I believe running the application with that argument just registers the application, it doesn't actually run the application as a service.  In fact, I think the application ends right after the application is registered.  At least that's what I noticed when stepping through the code with the debugger.  I'm not sure if there's any other commands that could actually tell `Windows` to run the application as a service.

Comment: Back in the ol' COM days, the usual way to register a COM out-of-process server was with the "/RegServer" parameter (try it!). The "/Service" was used to tell the executable to run in "server mode", that is, without a GUI. Naturally, your program may use that differently (note the '-' instead of '/'). But from the registry settings I'd say that is correct. If the program fail to start, that may be the cause of your problem. Finally, some COM servers were also Windows Services (but not all) and had to be run as such. Again the '/RegServer' flag should do the trick.

Comment: Actually, I use /RegServer on PFMQListen.exe.  I'm not exactly sure what the differences are between /RegServer and /Service, but I want to start PFAdapterMng.exe and PFTraceService.exe as services, through services.msc.  Using /RegServer does not add the applications to services.msc.  This is all because the Windows 2000 production server had it configured like this.

Comment: When you use /RegServer the program registers itself as a server/service and then exits. When you use /Service the program works as a service. When it is started by services.msc it should be using the /Service flag. But if your /RegServer does not work, maybe that is the problem. And looking at the logs, it is weird that it tries the "InprocServer32" key but not the "LocalServer32" or "LocalService", just as if you where specifying CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER in the CreateInstance call, instead of CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER...

Comment: Well, here's the code that has to do with `/Service`, `/RegServer`, and `/UnregServer`.

http://pastebin.com/6Bf0mZtY

Comment: Oh, my bad! /RegServer registers the program as a local server (a program run when needed that creates the COM object), while /Service registers the program as a System service. Other than that, they should behave similarly. Have you tried using both? And launching the EXE without options?

Comment: Well, `PFAdapterMng.exe` has to be a system service, or that's what I've been told.  I believe I did try using `/RegServer` at the beginning to debug the application, but I found a better solution by just implementing a `while(true) Sleep(100);` loop so I can attach the debugger at that point.  I never got to this point of the application's code when runnig as `/RegServer`, so I guess it could work.  I think they want it to be run as a service under another identity though, so I don't think running it as `/RegServer` is the solution.  I need to get it to work as a system service.

Comment: The process I use to start the application is by going to `services.msc`, and starting `PFAdapterMng.exe` from there.  I don't know if that's what you mean by 'without options'.

Comment: Hi, I tried using `/RegServer` again, and it worked.  The first time I tried using `/RegServer`, I just unregistered everything using `/UnregServer`.  This time, I also deleted the component from `Component Services` which I needed to have because I wanted to run `PFAdapterMng` under another identity.

So, it seems like everything works when running on `/RegServer` and double-clicking the applications.  However, I would like everything to run under a different configuration.  I updated my question with the configuration that I need.